# How can I extract this key alone from this multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, associative-array

How can I extract the values of the "attributes" array from this multidimensional array?

```
$json ='[
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attributeID": 3216,
            "attributeValue": "white",
            "skuImageUrl": "image.jpg"
          },
          {
            "attributeID": 450,
            "attributeValue": "S",
            "attributeDisplayName": "gray"
          }
        ],
        "cargoNumber": "",
        "amountOnSale": 446,
        "skuCode": "3740158232110",
        "skuId": 3740158232110,
        "specId": "94d1d179497744028aa76873afdeba62",
        "consignPrice": 18.5
      },
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "attributeID": 3216,
            "attributeValue": "Walking",
            "skuImageUrl": "ball.jpg",
            "attributeDisplayName": "waiting"
          },
          {
            "attributeID": 450,
            "attributeValue": "M",
            "attributeDisplayName": "stay"
          }
        ],
        "cargoNumber": "",
        "amountOnSale": 0,
        "skuCode": "3740158232111",
        "skuId": 3740158232111,
        "specId": "cef93beef156f1799e736c649f36efae",
        "consignPrice": 18.5
      }
]'
```

I have tried using for loops but I am getting confused. Decided to try foreach loops but ended up being more confused.  Please, how can I achieve this? I mean using only the attribute array from the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$jsonD = json_decode($json);
var_dump($jsonD[0]->attributes);

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
    ["attributeID"]=>
    int(3216)
    ["attributeValue"]=>
    string(5) "white"
    ["skuImageUrl"]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["attributeID"]=>
    int(450)
    ["attributeValue"]=>
    string(1) "S"
    ["attributeDisplayName"]=>
    string(4) "gray"
  }
}

foreach($jsonD[0]->attributes as $attribute){
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but does `json_decode` have some requirements like and certain version of php and so? There is a small listing that I found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: It lists the versions: (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7, PECL json >= 1.2.0)

Comment: Great ! You might add the `php` requirements too if (absolutely) necessary. Anyways most people should have now switched to php 7.x as the 5.x branches have already reached end of life.